# Duplicate results with GroupBy using Linq Query Expression but not using Fluent Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Having the following Linq Fluent Expression:
The group by code is the following:

```
var list2 = trains.GroupBy(t => t.Country.ToUpper(),
            t => t.Carriages,
            (train, carriages) => new
            {
                Country = train,
                TotalCarriages = carriages.Count(),
                SumCarriage = carriages.SelectMany(c=>c).Sum(l=>l.Length)
            }).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

If I try to translate fluent to linq q expression I have duplicated values althought I' am using Country.ToUpper() in the groupBy:

```
   var query = (from t in trains
                group t by new {Country = t.Country.ToUpper(), t.Carriages}
                into g
                select new
                {
                    Country = g.Key.Country,
                    TotalCarriage = g.Key.Carriages.Count,
                    SumCarriage = g.Key.Carriages.Sum(c => c.Length)

                }).ToList();
```

[image]

I can't explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used method syntax you were not grouping on two different values, rather you were grouping on *only* the country and transforming all of the elements into `Carriages`.  If you wanted to use query syntax to do that the syntax would be:

```
var query = (from t in trains
             group t.Carriages by t.Country.ToUpper()
             into g
             select new
             {
                 Country = g.Key,
                 TotalCarriages = g.Count(),
                 SumCarriage = g.SelectMany(c => c).Sum(l => l.Length)
             }).ToList();
```